# Php and unix grep backslashing does not work

Tags: php, regex, unix, sed

I have a fairly simple problem I just cannot seem to find a solution. I want to delete a line containing a certain string in all the files in a directory on my website. This string contains double quotes though. I have been trying to find a solution using backslashing but its does not work.

The string I want to replace is:`session_register("c$key");`

I'm using this php and unix code:

```
$command = "sed -i '/session_register(\"c$key\")/d;' ./*";
$output = shell_exec($command);
```

I want to delete this line because session_register is outdated.
It does not do anything but does not give me an error. What is the problem or how should I backslash?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: No error, just nothing is happening

Comment: What's the correct "unescaped" version (i.e. the version that works when you type it in to the command line)? Something like `sed -i '/session_register("cfoo")/d' ./*` ?

Comment: session_register("c$key"); is the string I want to remove

Comment: Yes, but you should provide an example of what works on the command line, and we can help you with how to escape it.

Comment: did you try running the sed command directly on a shell, and see if it works?

Comment: You mean this: `sed -i '/session_register("c$key")/d;' ./*` ? $key is not actually a variable its part of the string I want to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to double escape `$` as well since `$` is special regex symbol means end of input. Also use single quote instead of double for your `$command` string assignment.

Try this:

```
$command = 'sed -i.bak \'/session_register("c\\$key")/d;\' ./*';
$output = shell_exec($command);
```